# All js files of a parent folder gone missing on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, git, github

My folder **Projects** having multiple projects, is being messed by something.

Tl;dr version: For some unknown reason, all of my javascript files contained in sub-directories of **Projects** dir, are gone. If a sub-directory contained a **.js** file only, the dir itself is gone too.

Here's the situation:

I had installed GitHub's software and was just trying to figure out how it works, wherein I did something that created a hidden folder named **.git**.

I created a new directory **test and stuff** inside the **Projects** directory, and cut-paste a few directories(projects) in it.

After a few days my mom had encountered a BSOD (message is pasted below) and on the next day I saw those cut-pasted directories were listed in the **Projects** directory as well as **test and stuff** directory too. I did found it strange but ignored it, considering that I might have done something wrong in GitHub's software, which brought back the files. **All of the above might not be relevant to my current issue.**

Today when I was working on a project, I found that my **js** directory is missing from all the **project-dir/www** directory. And all had a common file- **app.js**.

**EDIT**: I just checked, all the **.js** files are missing inside this Project's subdirectories. And if any sub-directory contained a **.js** file only, the dir itself is gone too.

PS: I do have a back-up of the important codes, but I would like to retrieve everything to save my time in future.

Message from the BSOD:

```
A problem has been detected and Windows has been shut down to prevent damage
to your computer.

The problem seems to be caused by the following file: ntoskrnl.exe

PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA

If this is the first time you've seen this stop error screen,
restart your computer. If this screen appears again, follow
these steps:

Check to make sure any new hardware or software is properly installed.
If this is a new installation, ask your hardware or software manufacturer
for any Windows updates you might need.

If problems continue, disable or remove any newly installed hardware
or software. Disable BIOS memory options such as caching or shadowing.
If you need to use safe mode to remove or disable components, restart
your computer, press F8 to select Advanced Startup Options, and then
select Safe Mode.
```

The dump file: http://puu.sh/iP60u/e167590c20.dmp

Comment: Don't know the BSOD's message cause mom had witnessed it. And after that BSOD, I have worked on those js files, so I am unsure if the BSOD is a reason. Also, I have edited my question.

Comment: The dump file gives this info: https://gist.github.com/keval5531/1b0d61f3ba7ed8273af9

Comment: I've added it within the question and uploaded the dmp file too. What else would you need?

Comment: I will get back with you.